# Is there a way how to store periodic number into a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

*(Python 3.8)*

Is there a way how to store for example whole result of 1/3 into a variable?

```
foo = 1/3
```

> and then foo will contain a periodic number (*0.333333333333333333...*)

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html

Comment: Why do I have a downvote? Why is this question bad? Now I wont be able to answer questions because someone gave me a downvote!

Comment: Wow and I cann't ask for 4 days. Can someone give me a reason for this please??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for rational numbers is contained in the `fractions` module.

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> Fraction(1, 3)
```

Unless there is a specific reason for this I would strongly advice you to stick with floating points as they are magnitudes faster than any software implementation.

Comment: and what about for example 8.632634657 where 632634657 is periodic?

Comment: Such a number will be a rational number. Finding the actual nominator and denominator however will require you to do some math.

Comment: You can always write the periodic part as a fraction, e.g. 0.632634657... with all the digits shown being periodic, can be rewritten to `Fraction(632634657, 999999999)`.